# Iron drive: does this fusion superengine require clarketech?

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, fusion

**For context:** this is a very far future sci-fi setting, dozens of millenia from now, where dyson swarms and interstellar travel are commonplace, bioengineering and tech are so advanced they merge together and planets are by many considered obsolete as a living space. I'm however still trying to keep it somewhat grounded in known physics, there's no FTL and true magic-like clarketech is appearing only as secret supertechnologies or artifacts, if ever.

All in all, the topic of this question is deffinitely not the most unhinged technology in the setting and I could easily handwave it in, but I still want to get an idea of how ridiculous it is exactly to be able to give it a fitting place.

**Question:**
the thing I call iron drive is an idea for a spaceship engine which would somehow make its hydrogen fuel go through a rapid chain of fusion all the way to iron, like the lifecycle of a large star but much smaller and faster. 
**Could something like this be even remotely possible? If yes, try to rank it from 1 to 10:**

- **1 = something we know how to do on paper**
- **10 = something which one could still call scientific and not blatantly lie**

**And add what you expect the thing to actually do and look like and why you gave it the rank you gave it.**

Comment: We've not (in practical terms) cracked the hydrogen=>helium transition yet. Isn't the answer self-evident since we don't all have pocket-sized fusion reactors? (Or any functional ones of whatever size  attached to the power grid)

Comment: I think its a lie until someone comes up with a plan

Comment: Oil-company/media/government conspiracy? Sounds feasible. @Slarty Well, Kugleblitz, that could work in favour of your scenario.

Comment: Lets change the scale to: 1 commercially available. 10 can be done in lab setting. 20 active R+D.  90 clark tech, 100 its not impossible by physics. Hydrogen fusion would be 12 or so. Fusing to iron would be 80+ or so. I would rate antimatter drive as 50  or so

Comment: You want us to explain what a fictional piece of machinery would look like when we can't even build a simple fusion generator in the first place? You want us to rank its scientific plausibility? VTC:Opinion-Based. What's the real problem here? What's stopping you from using the idea and moving forward?

Comment: Need to have some option that says its not possible by physics as we understand it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can we fuse hydrogen all the way to iron at your tech level? Sure, why not? If stars can do it so can we.

Would we use it for propulsion at your tech level? Probably not, no.

Why? Because the energy density of hydrogen is lousy compared to that of antimatter. If your civilisation has mastered subatomic physics to the point where they can fuse hydrogen to iron in a controlled reactor, then they surely also have the ability to make and store antimatter. Consequently they'd be far better off performing the fusion reaction in a stationary power plant, using the energy to generate antimatter, and then using the antimatter for propulsion.

On the other hand, antimatter is dangerous, and while your civilisation likely has a lot of practice in handling it safely there might be situations where a safer fuel like hydrogen is preferred, even if it comes at a big cost in specific impulse. So you might find your iron drive being used in those cases. However, in that case the issues in Monty Wild's answer come in to play - going all the way to iron likely requires a huge increase in complexity (and hence weight) for only a relatively small gain in efficiency, so it might be that you would only go to helium in this case, or maybe carbon or oxygen, even if you had the tech to go all the way to iron.

Answer (score 15):

To [fuse hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain) (not deuterium or tritium) to helium alone is a slow process.  Just getting a given proton to fuse with another to form a deuterium nucleus is said to take billions of years, which is why we impatient humans go to all the effort of finding deuterium and tritium to put into our fusion reactors, which are still not able to produce a net gain in energy at the time I write this.

To get atomic nuclei to fuse requires a very large amount of pressure and temperature (which are almost the same thing).  This is achievable by either piling up a whole lot of hydrogen in one place and letting gravity do the work - which is called a star - or by using lasers and/or powerful magnetic fields to do the compression, which takes energy, and as of now, more energy than you get back from the reaction.

In order to fuse matter more quickly, you need *really* high temperatures and pressures.  You can do this by piling up more matter in one place, basically by building a bigger star, or by putting more energy into your compression mechanism.  The trouble with putting more energy into a compression mechanism is that to make a viable, net-energy-producing reactor, you need to get out more energy than you put in, which in the real world is proving very hard to do.  The trouble with fusing hydrogen to Iron is that the [binding energy curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Binding_energy_for_atoms) shows us that you get a lot of energy for fusing hydrogen to helium (~7 MeV), but only a little more for fusing Helium all the way up to Iron (~1.8
MeV).  Can you get back enough energy from all these extra fusion steps to justify the extra power it takes to run these more powerful compression devices?

[image: Nuclear Binding Energy]

Now, assuming that you *can* make a reactor that can apply pressure equivalent to that within a 130-250 solar mass star during a [pair-instability supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair-instability_supernova) without consuming more energy than is yielded, you can fairly quickly get all the way to Nickel-56, which will decay within a fairly short time to Cobalt-56 and then to Iron-56.

However, a pair-instability supernova effectively spreads the star's remaining mass out over a wide volume, blowing it apart completely and leaving no stellar remnant behind.  This is not what we want to happen in a fusion reactor, unless it is intended to be a bomb.

If our fusion reactor is capable of remaining intact during this runaway fusion reaction, we may get an unwanted side-effect, [photodisintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodisintegration), which is an energy-absorbing process that can lead to inward pressures so outweighing the normal outward energy-producing processes that the reaction mass would collapse, leading to synthesis of atoms heavier than Iron, or even the production of a black hole.

Of course, producing uranium is only going to absorb around 1 MeV of the total energy production, but a black hole is the last thing that you want.  Depending on its size, it may either begin ripping apart your reactor, or it may evaporate due to [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation), which emits a whole lot of energetic gamma rays.

Now, if we're trying to use a fusion reactor as a torch drive, we're trying to achieve the greatest net gain in energy possible.  *If* the energy cost in matter confinement isn't so great that it completely consumes the relatively small gain in energy from fusing Helium to Iron, we're not likely to get a whole lot of extra energy... but we will be getting a pretty efficient thrust, given the high mass of the ejected reactants.

However, I believe that this 'Iron Drive' is Clarketech.  The reactor would have to be huge in order to contain the necessary mass to produce and sustain the reaction, and realistically, it would be so heavy as to make for a poor spaceship.  It would have low accelerations, and it would likely need some sort of [Bussard ramscoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet) to keep it fuelled.

Answer (score 3):

There's very little reason to fuse heavier elements in general, partially because it is technically much harder (you need higher pressures and higher temperatures even than the regular flavors of fusion) and the energy yield per fusion is lower (see Monty Wild's chart) and the losses are higher (eg. via [neutrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-burning_process#Neutrino_losses) pair production) which means the yield per unit mass of fuel becomes even worse (because each fusion involves many more nucleons than hydrogen-fuelled reactions).

That's not to say that fusion of heavier elements than hydrogen or helium is completely useless, however.

Waaay back in the dark ages of 1975, Daniel Whitmire proposed what he called the Catalytic Ramjet. The paper is referenced online ([Relativistic spaceflight and the catalytic nuclear ramjet](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0094576575900636)) but I'm not aware of a legitimate source of the paper that's not behind a paywall. The basic principle is that the classic Bussard ramjet reaction, proton-proton fusion, is a complete nom-starter because it relies on the decay of a diproton to deuterium which is mediated by the weak nuclear force and very, *very* slow (this is one reason why hydrogen burning stars last a very long time on the main sequence, whereas helium burning ones do not).

Whitmire proposed using the [CNO cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) fusion process found in some large stars, whereby single protons (as a Bussard ramjet might harvest from the interstellar medium) fuse with a carbon, nitrogen or oxygen atom building up heavier nuclei each time. The neat bit is that the heavy elements don't get "used up" as the final stage, $\ce{^1H + ^{15}N -> ^{12}C + ^4He}$ with the four protons absorbed in the process shooting off as an alpha particle for handy direct energy conversion or thrust and (in theory) the heavy carbon being retained for re-use. There are other proton-consuming cycles, such as [Neon-Sodium and Magnsium-Aluminum](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-NeNa-cycle-and-its-link-to-the-MgAl-cycle_fig1_304003211), but as those elements get heavier the reactions get more and more inconvenient and less rewarding.

Of course, Bussard ramjets are basically impractical in the real world... drag on the interstellar medium just makes life too difficult, and the solar system is in a bit of a thin area of the ISM anyway just to make things harder. Some of the engineering difficulties are covered in this presentation by A. A. Jackson: [The Interstellar Ramjet: Engineering Nightmare](http://www.aiaahouston.org/Horizons/Ramjet_IRG.pdf). If you had some way to work around some or more of these issues... ways to generate more intense magnetic fields, perhaps with monopoles, highly efficient UV lasers, amazing high temperature high power superconductors, super refractory materials, efficient gamma voltaics, who knows what else... you might be able to justify fusion spacecraft with reactions involving stuff heavier than boron. The monopoles are certainly quite magic and have their own serious implications on the physics in your world, but the other issues might be solvable without recourse to Clarke's third law.

Antimatter probably makes for better rocketry (with all its accompanying risks and inconvenience of course), but for interstellar flight using reaction engines is a losing proposition and you should be using beams instead.